# SharePoint : How to authenticate user using REST webservices

Tags: rest, authentication, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am developing a mobile app which will integrate sharepoint features using it's REST api's.
All the GET webservice are working but for POST webservices authentication token is required which user gets after authentication.
I couldn't understand how to implement that authentication.
Any help?

Comment: Have you seen this? [Authorization and authentication for apps in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142384.aspx)

Comment: Are you using sharepoint 2010 or 2013? please specify the tags appropriately